# C# Getting Just Date From Timestamp

Tags: c#, sql, timestamp

If I have a timestamp in the form: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm

How can I just extract the date from the timestamp?

For instance, if a timestamp reads: "2010-05-18 08:36:52:236" what is the best way to just get 2010-05-18 from it.

What I'm trying to do is isolate the date portion of the timestamp, define a custom time for it to create a new time stamp.  Is there a more efficient way to define the time of the timestamp without first taking out the date, and then adding a new time?

Comment: You need a string representation of the date of just removing the time part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DateTime.Parse("2010-05-18 08:36:52:236").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Did you get a chance to read the second part of my question?  If there is a preferred way to do this, I would really like to know. 

Otherwise, what you have written here seems legit, Thanks.

Comment: Well what do you mean by 'more efficient' ? If you want it faster, you could compare different methods with a profiler ? I think the method Andomar suggested will be faster ? (The substring)

Comment: Gives a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception on my machine

Comment: Yeah you should use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture somewhere

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `DateTime` type:

```
DateTime original = DateTime.Parse(str);
DateTime modified = original.Date + new TimeSpan(13, 15, 00);
string str = modified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Your format is non-standard, so you'll need to call `ParseExact` instead of `Parse`:

```
DateTime original = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substring`:

```
"2010-05-18 08:36:52:236".Substring(0, 10);
```

Or use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2010-05-18 08:36:52:236", 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out date))
{
   date = date.Date; // Get's the date-only component.
   // Do something cool.
}
else
{
   // Flip out because you didn't get a real date.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the .Date member on the DateTime

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime midnightDate = date.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.Date; //will give you midnight today

x.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //use these method calls to modify the date to whats needed.
```

Comment: DateTime is immutable. You can't modify the date - you're creating a new one, which you happen to be throwing away instead of storing in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and fastest) way to do this is to convert the date to an integer as the time part is stored in the decimal part.

Try this:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(int, @yourdate))
```

So you convert it to an integer and then back to a data and voila, time part is gone.

Of course subtracting this result from the original value will give you the time part only.